# Filter array based on array of filters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of users and also an array of filters.

I need to filter users based on the array of filters but when I do it will filter on one array but not the others

My filters object looks like this:

```
filters: {
  levels: [],
  locations: ['Laois'],
  subjects: ['Art']
}
```

My users look like this:

```
const users = [
  {
    email: 'example1@gmail.com',
    levels: ['Ordinary'],
    location: 'Laois',
    subjects: ['Art', 'German']
  },
  {
    email: 'example2@gmail.com',
    levels: ['Higher', 'Ordinary'],
    location: 'Laois',
    subjects: ['English', 'German']
  }
]
```

Based on the filter above, once filtered the users should only be one because it contains 'Art' and 'Laois':

```
[{
    email: 'example1@gmail.com',
    levels: ['Ordinary'],
    location: 'Laois',
    subjects: ['Art', 'German']
  },
]
```

But I am still getting the two users:

*EDIT*
My Code:

```
applyFilter = (visable) => {
    let { filters, users } = this.state;
    const { subjects, locations, levels } = filters;


    let filteredUsers = [];
    const filteredData = users.filter((user) =>
      user.subjects.some(subject => subjects.includes(subject)) ||
      locations.some(location => location === user.location) ||
      user.levels.some(level => levels.includes(level))
    );

    console.log(filteredData)


    if (!subjects.length && !locations.length && !levels.length) {
      filteredUsers = users;
    } else {
      filteredUsers = filteredData;
    }

    this.setState({
      filterModalVisible: visable,
      filteredResults: filteredUsers.length >= 0 ? filteredUsers : [],
    });
  }
```

Comment: please add your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `filter` and `every` methods by checking if every element from the filters value exist in the user value with the same key.

```js
const filters = {"levels":[],"locations":["Laois"],"subjects":["Art"]}
const users = [{"email":"example1@gmail.com","levels":["Ordinary"],"locations":"Laois","subjects":["Art","German"]},{"email":"example2@gmail.com","levels":["Higher","Ordinary"],"locations":"Laois","subjects":["English","German"]}]

const res = users.filter(user => {
  return Object.entries(filters)
    .every(([key, value]) => {
      if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        return value.every(filter => {
          return user[key] && user[key].includes(filter)
        })
      } else {
        return user[key] == value
      }
    })
})

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `filter()`

```js
const filters = {
  levels: [],
  locations: ['Laois'],
  subjects: ['Art']
}

const users = [
  {
    email: 'example1@gmail.com',
    levels: ['Ordinary'],
    location: 'Laois',
    subjects: ['Art', 'German']
  },
  {
    email: 'example2@gmail.com',
    levels: ['Higher', 'Ordinary'],
    location: 'Laois',
    subjects: ['English', 'German']
  }
]

var res = users.filter(info => info.location==filters.locations[0] && info.subjects.includes(filters.subjects[0]));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a generic solution for any filter key by using [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

- Use `filter` to validate each entry against all the filter conditions
- If an filter condition has an empty list, continue to check for next condition
- For **locations**, as the `filter key` is **different** from the `key in object`, add a specific check for that where we check for location to be included in the locations array
- For other fields, check for existence of atleast 1 entry in array that exists in filter value. If there exists a value, continue to check for next condition.
- After condition check, confirm if the entry is valid, if not break the loop and return false

```js
let filters = {levels: [],locations: ['Laois'],subjects: ['Art']};
let users = [{email: 'example1@gmail.com',levels: ['Ordinary'],location: 'Laois',subjects: ['Art', 'German']},{email: 'example2@gmail.com',levels: ['Higher', 'Ordinary'],location: 'Laois',subjects: ['English', 'German']}];

users = users.filter(v => {
  let response = true;
  for (let filter in filters) {
    if(!filters[filter].length) continue;
    if(filter === "locations") {
      response = response && filters.locations.includes(v.location)
    } else response = response && v[filter].some(f => filters[filter].includes(f));
    if(!response) break;
  }
  return response;
});
console.log(users);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using filter inside filter

```js
const filters = {
  levels: [],
  locations: ['Laois'],
  subjects: ['Art']
}

const users = [
  {
    email: 'example1@gmail.com',
    levels: ['Ordinary'],
    location: 'Laois',
    subjects: ['Art', 'German']
  },
  {
    email: 'example2@gmail.com',
    levels: ['Higher', 'Ordinary'],
    location: 'Laois',
    subjects: ['English', 'German']
  }
]
console.log(users.filter((e) => {
  var arr = e.subjects.filter((x) => filters.subjects.includes(x))
  if (arr.length > 0 && filters.locations.includes(e.location))
    return e
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to use `&&` instead of `||` if you want to match all conditions
2. As per your requirements, you need all of them to match if filter array is empty, so you can just bypass the check for that case

```js
applyFilter = (visable) => {
    let { filters, users } = this.state;
    const { subjects, locations, levels } = filters;

    const filteredResults = users.filter((user) =>
        (!subjects.length || user.subjects.some(subject => subjects.includes(subject))) &&
        (!locations.length || locations.some(location => location === user.location)) &&
        (!levels.length || user.levels.some(level => levels.includes(level)))
    );

    this.setState({
        filterModalVisible: visable,
        filteredResults
    });
}
```